# Why the preposition “à” in “à cette saison”

Tags: sens, usage, prépositions

In the sentence

> On pourrait aller dans la forêt, c'est magnifique à cette saison.

In which sense is «à» used?

I searched the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) 
but être doesn't seem to be in the list of verbs.

Comment: Although *“être à” does* appear several times in the TLFi entry, I doubt there is an entry for this use. I think your sentence should read *“C’est magnifique en cette saison”*. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Édouard:J'ai modifié ma question :-)

Comment: La phrase est définitivement incorrecte. Encore une fois, d’où vient-t-elle ? Tu l’as lue quelque part, tu l’as entendue ? Distinguer les « à » et les « en » n’est pas toujours simple à l’oreille, surtout avec certains accents.

Comment: @Édouard: Merçi! I have read it in my book. Maybe a typo?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora I keep seeing you write "merçi", so I just want to say you don't need the cedilla, it's spelled "merci" as *i* is a soft vowel.

Comment: Please use http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ when linking to the TLF, as links on http://atilf.atilf.fr/ expire after a few minutes.

Comment: There is an occurrence of *à cette saison* in the TLF article (citation by Maupassant @Édouard). I think *en cette saison* is more common however.

Comment: Might be symmetry with `à cette période de l'année`. I do use "à cette saison" though, sometimes I find it flows more easily than "en cette saison".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le *[Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)* classe « à cette saison » dans le sens I.E.3 : *à* introduit un complément circonstanciel de temps, comme dans « à l'aube » (*at sunrise*) ou « à une date » ou « au printemps ».

On dit [plus couramment](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+cette+saison%2Cen+cette+saison&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=) « en cette saison ». Le TLF voit dans « à cette saison » une nuance : pour un évènement qui a une durée, *à* se réfère au début de la période alors que *en* se réfère à toute la période. Je ne perçois pas vraiment cette nuance.

Comment: J'ai plussoyé. Si on disait « On pourrait aller dans la forêt, c'est magnifique **cette saison** » sans aucunes propositions devant **cette saison**, quel écart et quelle variation de sens y aurait-il, par opposition à **à cette saison** et **en cette saison** ?

Comment: @LePressentiment Si j'entendais « c'est magnifique cette saison », je me dirais soit que j'ai mal entendu, soit que le locuteur a dit « c'est magnifique, cette saison », ce qui signifie « cette saison est magnifique ».